# How to add weather forecast on desktop?

Tags: indicator, applet, weather

Currently Ubuntu shows the weather information of your selected cities in the calendar indicator. There is also an applet for GNOME Panel that shows forecast for US & Canada cities only.

What is the best option to add more weather information including forecast (such as five-day forecast) on the Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lovely indicator applet that is not in the repositories but is [here](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator) on launchpad.

Here is a picture of it in action:

[image]

Here is the code to install it via terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lorenzo-carbonell/atareao

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

Comment: Actually, the screenshot and the Launchpad link is for the app in the Natty repos - indicator-weather. There is also a PPA for Lucid and Maverick, but it is `ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa`.